# How to move the mouse cursor from user code?

Tags: c++, linux, input, xorg

My data comes from an arduino (which gets it from a sensor).
I'd like to have the data processed by an user program (after reading it from /dev/ttyUSB0 ).
After that I need to control the mouse cursor using the output of the program.
(I'd really like to avoid writing a kernel driver at this moment.)

What is the recommended way to do this(on a Linux environment)?
Perhaps a library on top of X...or some tool/script I can directly pipe the data into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from [dzone](http://dzone.com/snippets/xlib-mousemove):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

void mouseMove(int x, int y)
{
    Display *displayMain = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    if(displayMain == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'apertura del Display !!!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    XWarpPointer(displayMain, None, None, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, y);

    XCloseDisplay(displayMain);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options I know of:

1. xte is a command line tool: http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte
2. if you can use python, xaut might be more to your liking: http://xautomation.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Thanks, will keep these in mind if I need them. For now, XWarpPointer seems to be doing nicely.

Answer (score -1):

Or with [node-x11](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11):

```
var x = 100; 
var y = 200;
require('x11').createClient(function(err, display) {
    display.client.WarpPointer(0, display.screen[0].root, 0, 0, 0, 0, x, y);
});
```