# sample c program for setting mouse pointer in LINUX

Tags: linux, mouse

can anyone post sample program to move mouse pointer to a specific position in Linux. also specify the dependencies.
 thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1: write an own program - [How to move the mouse cursor from user code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20581343/how-to-move-the-mouse-cursor-from-user-code)

Way 2: use something ready: http://tuxradar.com/content/xdotool-script-your-mouse

The main dependency is the X libraries. The rest depends on the approach, or specify this question more detailed.

Comment: i just want to move my mouse pointer to a particular position in c/c++ program. i want to implement this on gesture recognition system.  i don't k now how to implement .. what kind details you need more.  the input is taken from hand gestures.

Comment: Then if you follow Way 1 from written above, you will find a source code example. Write it to file main.cpp and give a command line `gcc main.cpp -lX11` to compile.